# Same CSS selector for id and class

Tags: css

I'm searching for a way to select all my div's that contain "copyright" as attribute value.

I tried it like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/f87ggqg6/

```
[name*="copyright"] {
   background:red;
}
```

But I can only select the class with copyright or I can select the id's with copyright. Is there a way to select id and class in one statement ?

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way would be:

```
[id*="copyright"], [class*="copyright"] {
   background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use

```css
div[class*="copyright"],
div[id*="copyright"] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="typo3-login-copyright-text">
  typo3-login-copyright-text
</div>

<div id="t3-copyright-notice">
  t3-copyright-notice
</div>

<div id="copyrightnotice">
  copyrightnotice
</div>
```

Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't one selector for both id and class. In this case you have to use two selectors:

```
div[class*="copyright"],
div[id*="copyright"] {
  background:red;
}
```